# Outlook.AppointmentItem change attachment file path

Tags: vba, outlook

**I want to change the attachment file path**. So far I've managed this:

```
Public WithEvents aaa As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Private Sub aaa_BeforeAttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment, Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim newPath
  'path where copy will be saved
  newPath = "D:\Test\" & Attachment.fileName
  
  Dim oFSO As Object
 
  Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   
  Call oFSO.CopyFile(Attachment.PathName, newPath, True)
  
  Dim att As Attachment
  'add the copy to AppointmentItem
  Set att = aaa.Attachments.Add(newPath, 7)
  'remove original attachment
  Attachment.Delete
  
End Sub

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If (TypeOf Item Is AppointmentItem) Then
        Set aaa = Item
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, this doesn't change the path of the file. I have also noticed OlAttachmentType enumeration and by inspecting the original Attachment I see that it has value 7, but how so when I don't have that value in OlAttachmentType enumeration?

Here is the image, the first one is the original attachment, second is after CopyFile of the original.

[image]

I can remove the original, that is easy, but how to force outlook to reference a new one by its path and not to copy it to C:\Users\sogrb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\5UUI14T4...

It is interesting that when you drag a file to the Outlook calendar Outlook references it like an external file no matter where that file resides. But when you try to add a file from VBA it can't be referenced outside Outlook cache (that folder above I've noted).

Comment: Please read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: @StureS open your outlook calendar, hit ALT + F11, copy this code in ThisOutlookSession and drag any file to it and that is it. Minimal!

Answer (score 1):

`OlAttachmentType == 7` is the new web attachment type (OneDrive).

If you want to replace the attachment, cancel the operation by setting the `Cancel` parameter to true and add the new attachment.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, let me try this

Comment: No, it doesn't work. With only Cancel = True and without deleting original attachments, now I have both there, please check the image

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to add the attachment as a web link attachment?

Comment: I am trying to grab an attached file and move it to a network location and then reference it like that.

Comment: But I don't think OOM would let you use type 7 when adding a new attachment. You need to either use olAttachByRef or use Redemption.

Comment: Thanks, can you just point me where to look about Redemption?

Answer (score 1):

In the code I see the following file location:

```
newPath = "D:\Test\" & Attachment.fileName
```

And then you are trying to attach this file specifying it as a web attachment:

```
Set att = aaa.Attachments.Add(newPath, 7)
```

You can't add local files as web attachments. Instead, you must upload the file to OneDrive and then attach a reference to it. Otherwise, your magical `7` value passed as an attachment type parameter will not work.

Comment: with the above code (from my question), I can't make any references outside  Outlook, all files will be copied to C:\Users\sogrb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\, even from network location or from onedrive (from my PC). Are you referring to C:\Users\sogrb\OneDrive\Public\test\ as OneDrive location?